# Mac OS X WebKit and CSS position:fixed scrolling

Tags: css, macos, cocoa, webkit, webview

We've run into an optimization problem using WebKit on Mac OS X that we're hoping someone can help us with.

We've written a Cocoa app for Mac OS X that essentially manages a single WebView that points to our online web site. Everything is working fine for the most part. However our web site uses CSS's position:fixed to keep a thin "header bar" locked to the top of the WebView, similar to the big orange "Welcome" bar at the top of StackOverflow.com.  We've determined that with position:fixed active, scrolling the WebView forces the entire web page to re-draw itself, which causes scrolling to be agonizingly slow. With position:fixed disabled, scrolling is very fast and fluid; only the page elements that are scrolled "into view" need to be drawn.

We know that this isn't a bug in our Cocoa app code, nor is it a problem with our HTML/CSS code. The same slow scrolling occurs using WebKit test code from Apple. We can point Apple's test code to http://www.StackOverflow.com as a test and we see the exact same behavior. There's also a test page in the Mozilla bug database that we've been using to test the problem (https://bug201307.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=139911). The odd thing is that some WebKit-based browsers on the Mac (eg, Safari and Chrome) don't have this problem; scrolling is always fast on pages using CSS's position:fixed with those two browsers.

Has anyone else experienced this problem with WebKit on OS X? If so, what can we do to speed up our scrolling? Thanks.

Comment: I think I am experiencing this.  Take a look at http://harrisnovick.com/orange and click on an article tile.  I will try to confirm if position:fixed is responsible for the poor scroll performance.

Comment: Harris, I do see some redraw issues with your site, but I don't think it's the same problem. If I hold the mouse cursor over one of your grid elements and scroll, then scrolling becomes a bit slower because all the grid elements are re-drawing themselves during the scrolling operation. However, if I hold the mouse cursor outside the window and scroll, the grid elements don't redraw themselves. Furthermore, the orange bar on the left side never seems to redraw itself.

Comment: This all makes me think that your's is a slightly different issue than mine. In our window, all elements redraw themselves consistently, including the position:fixed one.

Comment: i'm also experiencing this, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I might be way off here as I'm not sure if the same will apply in your web view, but using a style that forces the nav onto its own layer may help.

Something like translateZ(0), or translate3d(0,0,0,). I've come across similar issues when building with Phonegap and applying some thought to layering really helped out.

I believe the browser can utilise hardware acceleration where a third dimension is involved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem: the fixed bar was flickering when I was scrolling the page.
So I forced the WebView to use layers and I fixed

```
    [w setWantsLayer:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my webview based mac app. It has header and footer with position:fixed css property. Latest webkit shipped with 10.10.x and above don't suffer from this issue. It happens in webkit for mavericks (10.9.x). I got it working by setting these properties for the webview

```
    [self.webView setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self.webView setCanDrawSubviewsIntoLayer:YES];
```